# How to stop URL rewrite for archives in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I was setting up url rewrite for wordpress blog to remove all dates from the url (www.example.com/2012/08/postname). I had to do it through htaccess because it was new design for established blog, and by doing it through htaccess whill change links within the post as well (for example, if author links to another article, he used www.example.com/2012/07/postname). So simply adjusting permalinks in backend would not work.

I have used this code to create rewrites:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$  http://www.example.com/$3
</IfModule>
```

Now, my archives stopped working because their url is something like www.example.com/2012/08/. Is there any way to stop rewrite rule only in case the url contains only dates(ex. www.example.com/2012/08/), but keep rewrite for all posts containing date(ex. www.example.com/2012/08/posttitle)?

Comment: Are you sure they did the link updates within posts via htaccess? AFAK htaccess only cchanges the URL versus the content of the page. What does the permalinks section of the admin tab like?

Comment: Did you also do the appropriate changes in the Permalinks section? I see your point why only this won't work, but I think you should do the respective changes in the Permalinks section, so that WordPress knows what to display for the requested link.

Comment: Don't know any details, but if you want rewrite only `/XXXX/XX/something` and NOT `/XXXX/XX/` just change the star `*` in your `RedirectMatch` to plus sign `+`

Comment: Second the `*` to `+`. I would also advise against using both RewriteRule and RedirectMatch, as they are from 2 different modules. mod_rewrite and mod_alias. This could lead to some very strange behaviour (at least to a non-apache-expert)

Comment: Changing * to + worked perfectly. Thank you Kamil and Garben!

Comment: I believe setting the WP permalinks should also change `.htaccess`